# Calculate cumulative binomial probability in R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the cumulative probability of a binomial series:

```
a=choose(5,0)*0.5^0*0.5^5
b=choose(5,1)*0.5^1*0.5^4
c=choose(5,2)*0.5^2*0.5^3
d=choose(5,3)*0.5^3*0.5^2
e=choose(5,4)*0.5^4*0.5^1
f=choose(5,5)*0.5^5*0.5^0

cumulative=sum(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

Is there any way to do this with a single command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For cumulative probability use `pbinom`:

```
pbinom(0:5,5,0.5)
[1] 0.03125 0.18750 0.50000 0.81250 0.96875 1.00000
```

For individual values, `dbinom`:

```
dbinom(0:5,5,0.5)
[1] 0.03125 0.15625 0.31250 0.31250 0.15625 0.03125
```

And for summing cumulatively use `cumsum`:

```
cumsum(dbinom(0:5,5,0.5))
[1] 0.03125 0.18750 0.50000 0.81250 0.96875 1.00000
```

Comment: thanks, sorry I actually wasn't clear enough. I would like to get each value instead of the cumulative values.